# How to POST data from textarea to PHP script and get response

Tags: php, html

It sounds an easy task but I'm still learning.
I have a textarea where I put data and I want to post it to a php script to decrypt it.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <html>
    <form action="php.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="input" name="input" rows="4" cols="50"</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="decrypt" class="button" value="decrypt" />
    </form>
    
    <p><?php echo $decrypt; ?></p>
    
    </html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
function Decrypt($ciphertext)
{
    $key = 1;
    $c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + $sha2len);
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
        return $original_plaintext;
    }
}
   
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $decrypt = Decrypt($_POST['decrypt']);
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Error I'm receiving `"Warning: Undefined array key "decrypt" on line20"`

Expected behavior: Output the original plaintext.

If you would like to test a valid encrypted line please use:

```
W9aMvbRmmN/52Kmv1rr9i59ecKu2KYIhrL+Mj+dD8VE3BtwUiFIEBqrRc/e3aw8li2GKKu4B3FVyx/dkRnNnmw==
```

Comment: first, include your textarea input inside your form. second, do a print_r($_POST); in your php script and report back what you get

Comment: Ok I updated the code please check, the result of print_r($_POST); isWarning: openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is only 5 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0 in C:\laragon\www\test\testhtml\php.php on line 11
`Array ( [input] => W9aMvbRmmN/52Kmv1rr9i59ecKu2KYIhrL+Mj+dD8VE3BtwUiFIEBqrRc/e3aw8li2GKKu4B3FVyx/dkRnNnmw== [decrypt] => decrypt )`

Comment: The `<textarea>` should have the `name="decrypt"`, not the submit button. Otherwise you're just passing through the literal string 'decrypt' to your function. Alternatively, you can use `Decrypt($_POST['input']);`

Comment: @ObsidianAge like this  `<textarea id="decrypt" name="decrypt" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea> `?

Comment: `$decrypt = Decrypt($_POST['input']);` Result=>`Array ( [input] => W9aMvbRmmN/52Kmv1rr9i59ecKu2KYIhrL+Mj+dD8VE3BtwUiFIEBqrRc/e3aw8li2GKKu4B3FVyx/dkRnNnmw== [decrypt] => decrypt )`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $decrypt = Decrypt($_POST['decrypt']);
}
```

and then some where else read the results:

```
<p><?php echo isset($decrypt)? 'Decryption answer is ' . $decrypt : 'answer goes here' ; ?></p>
```

also you should have the text area in the form :

```
<form action="php.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="input" name="decrypt" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

The name is so important . The post array takes what ever input names inside your form and makes it key in $_POST array and the value of it is what the user types in it.

Comment: Hi, I got this error Warning: Undefined array key "input" in C:\laragon\www\test\testhtml\php.php on line 20
Array ( [decrypt] => W9aMvbRmmN/52Kmv1rr9i59ecKu2KYIhrL+Mj+dD8VE3BtwUiFIEBqrRc/e3aw8li2GKKu4B3FVyx/dkRnNnmw== [submit] => Submit )

Comment: yes because now your post keys are only `decrypt` and `submit` why ? because they are in name attributes of your form `name="decrypt"` and  `name="submit"` .

Comment: I still can't solve it, I have this error on the html page: `Warning: Undefined variable $decrypt in C:\laragon\www\test\testhtml\test2.php on line 9` which is referring to my html section Line 9 = `<p><?php echo $decrypt; ?></p>`

Comment: Thanks, the last reported issue is gone, but I still get : `Warning: Undefined array key "input" in C:\laragon\www\test\testhtml\php.php on line 20
Array ( [decrypt] => W9aMvbRmmN/52Kmv1rr9i59ecKu2KYIhrL+Mj+dD8VE3BtwUiFIEBqrRc/e3aw8li2GKKu4B3FVyx/dkRnNnmw== [submit] => Submit )`

Comment: i confused isset() with !empty() forgive my mistake

Comment: It's ok, is it possible that you try my code on your laptop please

Comment: i think all you have to do is     `$decrypt = Decrypt($_POST['decrypt']);`

Comment: I tried it but didn't work

Comment: I tried your updated solution but it would show blank page

Comment: here is a [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_SMl4kSXbq5f6k4BCgYrQF7eS_6Gz6n/view?usp=sharing0) that i made and works 100% .

Comment: `<form action="php.php" method="post">` this will submit the form to another page php.php but in my code i suggest `<form action="" method="post">` to make the page submit the form to itself

Comment: thank you @Yasser i tried your code again but it's not working can you please retry it?

Comment: create a folder `test100` in www and put the index.php file in it . to see your page start your wamp server 1st and then search in the browser  for `localhost/test100/` .

Comment: what i meant is that it doesn't decrypt anything, your code doesn't include the decrypt function, can you test it please

Comment: yes just replace my decrypt method with yours . My code is just for sending user input to your server